# accessory type repeats for the reused cells in uitable view

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to apply checkmark as accessory type to a selected item in a uitable view. but the checkmark appears for all reused cells. How can we avoid this problem?
code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        if ([[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ringtone_id] isEqualToString:selId] ) {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }

    }

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.textLabel.text = [[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ringtone_name] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


    }

    // Configure the cell...

     if ([[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ringtone_id] isEqualToString:selId] ) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
     } else {
       cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
     }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ringtone_name] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    return cell; }
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add the `else` case to unmark the cells that you don't want to be marked, like this:

```
if ([[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ringtone_id] isEqualToString:selId] ) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    // Configure the cell...

        if ([[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ringtone_id] isEqualToString:selId] ) {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ringtone_name] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    return cell;
}
```