# multiple rows gets selected while selecting a single row on tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

am having this strange issue while am selecting any of the row from TableView another row is also get selected ,  say i have a tableView with multiple rows in my case its 11 and multiple selection with the accessory of tick mark is enabled (when i select a row a tick is marked on the selected row ) so when am selecting my first row ,  then row number 8 is also got selected (i can see the tick mark in the row number 8 but i selected only the row number 1 ) when i select another row number 2 my row number 9 is also get selected dont know why this is happening if anybody knows anything about this behaviour then please let me know it'll be so helpful for me  , below is the code of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` :

```
var selectedTextLabels = [NSIndexPath: String]()
var selectedTextLabelsName = [NSIndexPath: String]()



    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! UsersTableViewCell

    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark){

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None;

        selectedTextLabels[indexPath] = nil
        selectedTextLabelsName[indexPath] = nil
     }else{
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark;

        if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark){

    if let Id = cell.channelIDLbl?.text {
                selectedTextLabels[indexPath] = Id
            }
            if let channelName = cell.lblChannelname?.text{

                selectedTextLabelsName[indexPath] = channelName
            }

         } 
}
```

cellForRowAtIndexpath:

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UsersTableViewCell


    if isFavoritesTabActive == true {

           let object : RChannels =     self.favoritesArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! RChannels


            cell.lblChannelname.text  = object.channelName

        let favorite = object.isFavorite

        if favorite == "true" {
            cell.favIcon.image = UIImage(named: "Favourite")

        return cell }

    else {

     let object : RChannels = self.noteObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! RChannels

            cell.lblChannelname.text  = object.channelName                

            let favorite = object.isFavorite

            if favorite == "true" {
                cell.favIcon.image = UIImage(named: "Favorite")

            }else {

                cell.favIcon.image = UIImage(named: "unFavorite") }


            return cell
        }
```

Comment: Can you share `cellForRowAtIndexPath` ?

Comment: You should update your model in didSelectRowWithIndexPath and set the accessoryType in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Remember that UITableViewCells are reused. Setting the accessoryType and not resetting it after it's been dequeued will cause it appear in cells for which it was not intended.

Comment: @ViktorSimkó please check my question

Comment: so any clue how am gonna reset it after dequeued ?? and you're right its only appearing as selected because when i printed the selected rows only the one that i actually selected was there @beyowulf

Comment: @ViktorSimkó well putting none in the accessory is not working as desired cause my selected rows are also get vanished when i scroll

Comment: @remyboys True, I've realised it also...

Comment: @ViktorSimkó please see my updated question maybe it'll help you a little ,  i haven't mentioned before that am putting the selected row's value into an Array.... please see the update

Answer (score 1):

checking inside the `channelIDLbl` array for existence of the cell's id at `cellforRowAtIndexPath` did the job

```
    if ((selectedTextLabels[indexPath]?.containsString("\(cell.channelIDLbl)")) != nil){


        cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
    }else {

        cell.accessoryType = .None
    }
```

for more detail please check this same  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610641/accessory-type-repeats-for-the-reused-cells-in-uitable-view)